# Не могу указать путь к файлу через char* (язык C)

Tags: c, файлы

После ввода строки программа завершается

```
    char tmp;
    char * test_path;

    FILE *T; //File

    puts("\nНачало теста, введите название документа с тестом\n");
    gets(test_path);

    T = fopen(test_path, "r"); \\ Проблема в этом месте
```

Файл (.txt) находится в той же директории что и исходный файл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выше уже сказали, что память для указателя не выделил. Но по факту тебе и не нужно выделять память. Просто создай массив длиной символов в 20-30, да и всё. А вместо `gets()` используй `fgets()`, чтобы не переполнить этот массив.

Answer (score 2):

`test_path` - это просто указатель. Что бы сохранить строку, сначала нужно выделить для нее память с помощью `malloc`.